# c# LinqToTwitter Retweet with Comment

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, linq-to-twitter

I am using LinqToTwitter and would like to recreate the Twitter Retweet functionality.

I am able to retweet something with this line:

```
var retweet = await Connection.RetweetAsync(tweetID);
```

But Twitter also offers the possibilty to add a comment while retweeting. Is there is a chance to this the same way Twitter does?

Thank You,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Retweet with comment is not a real retweet. In fact you can see on the Twitter website that if you add a comment to your retweet, the retweet count is not increased.

Retweet with comment is called `quoted tweet`. A quoted tweet is simply a tweet containing a URL to the tweet "retweeted".

If you want to have the exact same behavior as Twitter you won't want to do a retweet. But if you do want a retweet (increasing the retweet count), you will have to invoke 2 methods, `publish quoted tweet` and `retweet`.

Comment: Sounds easier than I thought, Thx!